# variable in SQL

Tags: sql, string, variables, db2

I have a DB2 table with two columns A and B storing alphanumeric values.I want to find whether a value(MyValue) exist in between A and B. I want my result to be : MyValue | A |  B

I could have used: `SELECT 'MyValue',A,B FROM TABLENAME WHERE(A < 'MyValue' AND B > 'MyValue')` but the constraint is, I have to search more than 10000 values with single query and want the result as below format.

Ex. value=W140686,0032090,0045790...etc

Expected Result:

```
MyValue      A          B
W140686 | W000000  | W999999
0032090 | 0000001  | 0500000
0045790 | 0000001  | 0500000
..
..
..
```

Any help / suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not using any server, using query in mainframe db2.
Don't know if something like this is possible:
SELECT MyValue,A,B FROM TABLENAME WHERE
(MyValue='W140686' and A < 'W140686' AND B > 'W140686')or
(MyValue='0032090' and A < '0032090' AND B > '0032090')or
..

Answer (score 1):

The BETWEEN predicate includes the end points. In this case, the result set will include the string 'MyValue' if it's equal to either the string in column A or the string in column B.

```
SELECT 'MyValue',A,B 
FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE 'MyValue' BETWEEN A AND B;
```

If you want to exclude the end points . . .

```
SELECT 'MyValue',A,B 
FROM TABLENAME 
WHERE 'MyValue' > A AND 'MyValue' < B;
```

For performance, you might want one index on the pair of columns {A, B}. For details, [read the execution plan](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_explain.dita?lang=en).

---

If you need to supply 10000 values to the WHERE clause, you should probably store them in a temporary table. Join the temporary table to TABLENAME.

```
-- DB2 syntax to create a temporary table is different. Look it up.
create temp table my_values (
 MyValue varchar(10) primary key
);

-- Insert the 10000 values here.
insert into my_values values
('W140686'),('0032090'), ('0045790');

select T1.MyValue, T2.a, T2.b
from my_values T1
inner join TABLENAME T2
        on T1.MyValue > T2.a and T1.MyValue < T2.b
```

The join predicate is the same as the WHERE clause in my earlier queries.

Comment: Hello Mike,
Thanks for replying.
But my problem is not '>' or Between but to include MyValue into my result set.
SELECT 'W140686',A,B FROM TABLENAME WHERE 'W140686' between A and B holds good and meets my expectation but when I have 10000 MyValue then what query can be used. I have also added a comment above with little more detail.Please see if you can help....Thanks...